# Javascript loading before HTML page error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I am just trying to get a very simplistic event handler working, however, 
I keep an getting an error:

```
Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

I am suspecting this is due to my javascript executing before my HTML is finished loading. And so I've tried wrapping my javascript in each of these:

```
$window.onload = function(){
$(window).bind("load", function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
```

This is the function call causing the error:

```
 var submit = document.getElementById("button");

    submit.onclick = function () {
            answer("text");
        }

function answer(x){
var response = new String("Thank you"); 
var a = document.getElementById(x);
a.textContent += response}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What variable / object is "submit" set to? I'm presuming that isn't set to a DOM object.

Comment: I'll edit it and add that to it

Comment: Are you verifying that there is a DOM element with `id="button"`? I don't see any validation / checking that the element is found. If you simply have `<button></button>` on your page that will return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery, then you might as well just do

```
$("#button").click(function() { answer("text"); });
```